# No Bluetooth Found on Ubuntu LTS 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, bluetooth

I am a complete noob when it comes to Ubuntu, so I have no idea how to fix this. My System's on dual boot. Bluetooth works on Windows 10. However, on Ubuntu it shows

> Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth.

Some info

```
cjk@bot:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; rfkill list; uname -r; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
--
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:2166]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
0a:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce GT 740M] [10de:1292] (rev a1)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:5775 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. HP "Truevision HD" laptop camera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5.0.0-37-generic
[    0.186208] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.231739] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.369949] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[   14.100991] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   30.777575] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[   30.822736] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.37
cjk@bot:~$
```

Comment: I have already answered similar question here askubuntu.com/a/1194503/890892

Comment: @TejasLotlikar, just checked your answer. When I write `bluetoothctl` I get `Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...` and its stuck there. I don't think that is the solution. I feel that it's a driver issue, which I do not know how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

A reboot alone didn't work for me. I had **success** after I rebooted (a second time) and held <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the system config, then reviewed the Wireless settings and verified that Bluetooth was enabled, then exited the config and finished the startup. At that time, Bluetooth was working again.

### TMI

Prior to the reboot, I ensured that I was *not* dealing with a softlock with `rfkill`. I tried to run `bluetoothctl`, but it only hung.

I also executed `/etc/init.d/bluetooth restart` prior to the second reboot, but I don't suppose that that had any bearing.